# Cucumber Html file Jenkins

Tags: cucumber, jenkins-plugins, cucumber-java

I am running a job in Jenkins that generates a HTML report with the specified json.

Ideally, I would want to upload this json and html to artifactory for storing results of previous builds. Is this possible? I have tried "Publish to Artifactory" but to no luck, that plugin in jenkins does not seem to upload any artifact.

Any thoughts help.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic artifactory integration to upload the artifacts.
[image]

Comment: I get a "Artifactory Build Info Recorder: no artifacts to deploy..." when updating the information

Comment: Hope you gave the pattern and path right to upload.
{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "./html/*.html",
            "target": "artifactory-repo-name"        
}
    ]
}

Comment: @Aarthy I am not sure I have the same plugin version because I am unable to see those fields when I select the Plugin. See Screenshot in original post above.

Comment: Ok, you were using Maven job and uploading artifacts from it?
As per screenshot, the artifactory server is not pointing to artifactory URL instead its pointing to Maven central I guess.